# Calculate how many sub-sequence does a long string contain

Tags: python

In this question, a sub-sequence means a string in which members are picked from the long string and they are in the same order as before.
For example, given a string "XXIIGUA", it contains 4 "XIGUA"

1. first 'X' + first 'I' + 'GUA'
2. first 'X' + second'I' + 'GUA'
3. second'X' + first 'I' + 'GUA'
4. second'X' + second'I' + 'GUA'

given a string "XXIIGGUUAA", it contains 32(2^5) "XIGUA", etc.

Now, the question is, when i input a random long string (length < 1000), how do i calculate the number of "XIGUA" it contains?

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck. See also: [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: `2**len(set(my_string))`

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that separates the input into characters and stores them in a list. It then finds how many times each letter occurs in the list and multiplies them.

Here is the code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

#test = "XXXXXIIIIGGGUUA"
test = "IXGUA"
def xigua(testStr):
    letterlist = [char for char in testStr]
    strLtrsOrder=list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(test).keys())
    uniqueLtrs = ["X", "I", "G", "U", "A"]
    if strLtrsOrder == uniqueLtrs:
        xiguaTotal = 1
        for letter in uniqueLtrs:
            xiguaTotal *= letterlist.count(letter)
    else:
        xiguaTotal = 0
    print(xiguaTotal)

xigua(test)
```

Output:

```
120
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! There is a small error, which is the most difficult part of this question.
For example, given a input string like "IXGUA", we can still have an output 1 by counting unique strings. But the output should be 0.(When we pick unique strings, we can not change the order, so there will be no "XIGUA")
So there may be a different way to solve this problem. QAQ

Comment: Ah, I'll see how to do this and update my answer!

Comment: @Dr.Toby I updated my answer. It will now make sure that the first time it reads a letter, it adds it to a dictionary. At the very end, the dictionary is converted to a list, and it's checked to see if it is equal to `uniqueLtrs`. If it is, it does the same as before, but if it isn't `xiguaTotal` is set to 0. It still won't work if you have a letter that's already been read come after the next letter. For example:`"XIXGUA"`.